# Hangfire function couldn't invoke in appService layer using asp boilerplate

Tags: c#, aspnetboilerplate

I've created a webhook(IAppservice) which triggers a hangfire job, Job is adding in Hangfire.Job record as scheduled. but not executing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement your background job in an interface which is being inherited by IDomainService.